# Android Tutorial 'HelloTabWidget'

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, tabs, android-manifest

I think I've added the code exactly as it says on the android tab layout tutorial and corrected any problems. The app seems to compile ok but when I run it on the emulator it says 'The application *** has stopped unexpectedly please try again'. Here are my files please let me know if you see any problem with the code.

there are 4 separate activity files.

```
package com.example.HelloTabWidget;


import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

public class AlbumsActivity extends TabActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_white))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}



}

package com.example.HelloTabWidget;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class ArtistsActivity extends TabActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_white))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}

}


package com.example.HelloTabWidget;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_white))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}}




 package com.example.HelloTabWidget;


import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class SongsActivity extends TabActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_white))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}}
```

This is the artists xml file in res/drawable (the images are present in res/drawable as well)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected, use grey -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_artists_grey"
      android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- When not selected, use white-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_artists_white" />
</selector>
```

This is the main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

this is the android manifest file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.HelloTabWidget" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".HelloTabWidget" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

</activity>
<activity android:name=".ArtistsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

</activity>
<activity android:name=".SongsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

</activity>
</application>


</manifest>
```

I have spend ages going over this looking for typos and found nothing, I've also spent ages looking on forums and nothing seems to adequately address why this doesn't work - I am new to this though so could be mistaken and maybe dont understand the answers but i dont think thats it.

Comment: the best idea would be to give the logcat output and also the line that gives you the exception.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment all your Activity.java classes look exactly the same as the HelloTabWidget.java which they probably shouldn't

Try:

**HelloTabWidget.java**

```
package com.example.HelloTabWidget;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); 
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(new Intent(this, ArtistsActivity.class)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(new Intent(this, AlbumsActivity.class)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class)));

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }
}
```

**ArtistsActivity.java**

```
package com.example.HelloTabWidget;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class ArtistsActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.artistslayout);

    // your code for this activity ... (not the same as HelloTabWidget.java)


    }
}
```

And the same for the other 2 Activity classes.

Comment: to add an explanation: HelloTabWidget.java runs at the launch of your application as defined in your AndroidManifest.xml. This HelloTabWidget.java then initializes the tabs and creates the activities (intents) running in your different tabs. This step must not be repeated in each of your activity.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work. I changed the HelloTabWIdget.java file for you suggestion and changed the code in the other activities to just a textview but the message is still that there is an error and the application must force close. I also tried it with my previous code in the HelloTabWidget.java file and just a textview for the onCreate method for the other activities and still no luck. Do you have any further suggestions? Sorry I'm new.

Comment: I had a small copy&paste error in my answer. The ArtistsActivity (+2 others) has to extend the standard Activity and you have to use different layouts than the main layout. I've uploaded the complete working example to http://www.boye.ch/HelloTabExample.zip